# Simplest XSLT to filter nodes based on child node attribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to use XSLT for copying mrss xml, but filter items that don't have `test` value in `label` attribute using XSLT.

Here is what I did so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
            <channel><xsl:apply-templates/></channel>
        </rss>      
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="channel/item[contains(media:category/@label,'test')] | channel/*[not(self::item)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="channel/item[not(contains(media:category/@label,'test'))]">
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Three things that I don't like in it:

- empty template to filter unmatched items,
- `rss`, and `channel` elements are already present in the source XML but I still need to put it into the XSL file
- I think that some things can be done with single XPath expression, but I don't know enough XPath and XSLT.

Can somebody can suggest better/simpler solution?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the better approach is to start with an identity template and go from there. The following should be all you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="channel/item[not(contains(media:category/@label,'test'))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, the only problem is that elements in source have indent, so there is empty line, in place of each item removed. How I can fix it?

Comment: The addition of an `xsl:strip-space` should fix that. Modified above.

Comment: How to add an OR filter for two words? Only the items in category "sport" OR "nature"?

Comment: @aborruso To reuse the example above, you could either use `channel/item[not(contains(media:category/@label, 'sport') or contains(media:category/@label, 'nature'))]` or you could use `channel/item[not(media:category/@label[contains(., 'sport') or contains(., 'nature')])]`